# Disabling the Font Family option in forms (ie a new Blog entry)

Tags: richhtmlfield

I have figured out how to disable font options when I am creating content using a page, or more importantly the PublishingWebControls:RichImageField.

But when users create a new blog entry, the modal dialog/form pops up and the font family option is visible. The thing is a 'blog' entry id a list item.

How do I edit the PublishingWebControls:RichImageField for a list item?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of history.

We wanted to lock down how users create content. So our goal was to disable the font family, font size and font color controls.

I always thought the key was to configure the RichHtmlField. It worked for page content, becuase the control was in a page layout. But for list items, there is/was no page layout for the RichHtmlField to be configured. So I figured that any solution would require cracking open Visual Studio.

But it turns out, it only took 2 simple lines of CSS ...

```
#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPEditTab\.Font-Large-0-0,
#Ribbon\.EditingTools\.CPEditTab\.Font-Large-0-1-1 { display:none; }
```

I hope this can help some people out because I have no idea how many days I blew trying to fix this.

Thanks